# Cannot upload relatively large video file using Razor Pages - "Request Entitiy Too Large"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, file-upload, razor-pages

I'm trying to create a web app where I can upload video files to the cloud and then play them back. I am having trouble with uploading relative large video files. When I Upload a relatively small video file everything works as it should.

I have done extensive research into this but I cannot seem to get anything to work. I have recreated my problem in a small example for demonstration purposes

Here is the .cshtml:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" asp-for="UploadedFile" />
    <input asp-page-handler="Upload" class="btn" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

And here is the .cshtml.cs

```
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 104857600)]
public class TrialUploadModel : PageModel
{

    [BindProperty]
    public IFormFile UploadedFile { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }


    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {

        Console.Write("Success!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        using (var stream = UploadedFile.OpenReadStream())
        {
            Console.Write(stream.Length);
        }
        return Page();

    }
}
```

As you can see I have added **[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 104857600)]** to the page and I have also created a web.config and extend the limit size there as well, but still I keep getting the same problem.

I have also increased the FormOptions in the StartUp.cs but still no luck:

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
{
    x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
    x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
});

services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
});
```

When I launch the application using IIS I get this:

[image: RequestTooLargeError]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For .NET Core 6 and Razor Pages, there are some tips in Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

In Program.cs, file limits are included as an option targeting the page that performs the upload:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options => 
{
options.Conventions
    .AddPageApplicationModelConvention("/[your cshtml page name with no extension]",
        model =>
        {
            model.Filters.Add(
            new RequestFormLimitsAttribute()
            {
                // Set the limit to 256 MB
                ValueLengthLimit = 268435456,
                MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 268435456,
                MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = 268435456
            });
           // model.Filters.Add(
           //     new RequestSizeLimitAttribute(268435456));
        });
    });
```

MultipartHeadersLengthLimit was added in the documentation, but I included other limits you would be interested in changing, too.

In your page model, include:

```
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 268435456)]
public class YourPageNameModel : PageModel
{ ...}
```

Note that to follow the documentation example, you must update the FileHelper.cs with the proper file signature if you are trying to upload a different extension. Otherwise, the page will return an invalid state.